# Using a weak acid to prevent the precipitation of Mg(OH)2

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, solubility, precipitation

I have this exercise in my chemistry book, and I have been staring at it for so long but unfortunately I have no single idea what to do and where to start. I will be so thankful for any help.

**$0.05$ moles of NH<sub>3</sub> are added to one liter of MgCl<sub>2</sub> of concentration $0.02$ mol/L.
How many moles of NH<sub>4</sub>Cl do we need to add in order to prevent the precipitation of Mg(OH)<sub>2</sub>?
Given K<sub>sp</sub>=8.4×10^(-12)  ; pK<sub>b</sub>=4.5**

My teacher's approach:

**The solution of Mg(OH)<sub>2</sub> is saturated at pH=10.4 since:
K<sub>sp</sub>=4s³
Then s=1.28×10^(-4) mol/L 
with [HO<sup>–</sup>] = 2s**

**pH=14+log[HO<sup>–</sup>]**

Afterwards, using Henderson–Hasselbalch equation, using the given and calculated values, we get

**[NH<sup>4+</sup>]=6.29×10^-3 mol/L**

I thought that the calculated value of $s$ is true when Mg(OH)<sub>2</sub> is put in pure water and not in a solution containing a weak base which decreases its solubility by common ion effect, so this method is not valid. But i don't know how to solve the problem. Can you help me please?
Sorry for the not perfect format. I did my best.

Comment: It is unclear to what pKb refers to. As pKb1+pKb2 of Mg(OH)2 is 1.8 resp 2.56 ( http://www.periodensystem-online.de/index.php?show=list&id=acid&prop=pKb-Werte&sel=oz&el=92 ), it must be pKb of NH3, which is 4.75, so 4.5 is quite incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Consider (1) for $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ dissolution equilibrium, (2) for ammonia acido-basic equilibrium.

Combining both, you get required concentration of $\ce{NH4+}$.

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{sp} &= \mathrm{pMg} + 2 \cdot \mathrm{pOH}\tag{1}\\
\mathrm{pOH} &= \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b, NH3} + \mathrm{pNH3} - \mathrm{pNH4+} \tag{2}\\
\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{sp} &= \mathrm{pMg} + 2 \cdot \left( \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b, NH3}+  \mathrm{pNH3} - \mathrm{pNH4+}\right) \tag{3}\\
  \mathrm{pNH4+} &= \frac 12 \left( \mathrm{pMg}  -  \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{sp} \right)    +  \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b, NH3}+  \mathrm{pNH3} \tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

where "$\mathrm{pX}$"  means "$-\log{X}$"
 resp. "$-\log{c_\mathrm{X}}$".